# Transactional Spring Boot test with MySQL 8 rolls back transaction, but row gets inserted anyway

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Normally when I do a Spring Boot app with Spring Data JPA, in the tests the transactions rollback automatically and the test database is not changed. This behavior isn't working, however, with MySQL8.

I have a trivial POJO called `Category`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "category_name")
    private String name;

    // ... constructors, getters and setters, etc, omitted ...
}
```

Here's my even more trivial repository interface:

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category,Integer> {
}
```

I have an existing database and here are my `application.properties` settings to access it:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dashboard
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=not_password
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

There are currently 10 categories in the table. My test checks for them, and another test inserts a new one.

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class CategoryRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository dao;

    @Test
    void findAll() {
        List<Category> categories = dao.findAll();
        assertEquals(10, categories.size());
    }

    @Test
    void insertCategory() {
        Category cat = new Category("Misc");
        assertNull(cat.getId());
        cat = dao.save(cat);
        assertNotNull(cat.getId());
        System.out.println(cat);
    }
}
```

Note that `@DataJpaTest` already includes `@Transactional`. The output of the second test is:

```
2019-10-03 14:26:48.844  INFO 91485 --- [    Test worker] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@67e4b73d testClass = CategoryRepositoryTest, testInstance = com.kousenit.simpledemo.dao.CategoryRepositoryTest@3913544f, testMethod = insertCategory@CategoryRepositoryTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@7314dd45 testClass = CategoryRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.kousenit.simpledemo.MyApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@3c6df497, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@8b9f8fd, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@15acb0c6, [ImportsContextCustomizer@76c5962 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@21f27cf2, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@67568498, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@4a3861f3]; rollback [true]
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        categories
        (category_name) 
    values
        (?)
Category{id=11, name='Misc'}
2019-10-03 14:26:48.880  INFO 91485 --- [    Test worker] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@67e4b73d testClass = CategoryRepositoryTest, testInstance = com.kousenit.simpledemo.dao.CategoryRepositoryTest@3913544f, testMethod = insertCategory@CategoryRepositoryTest, ...
```

The problem is, after the test is over, I still have the new category in the database. With H2, the transactions rolled back and it wasn't there, but with MySQL 8 even though the rollback is happening, the inserted item remains.

What's different here? How do I fix it so the insert is reset at the end of the test?

Comment: I have run into same issue, did you ever get to bottom of this?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Sorry. I wound up using an existing database.

Answer (score 0):

As transaction needs to be commited explicitly. Therefore I think you need to set property of autocommit to false. like this

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
```

Comment: I tried that by adding `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.autocommit=false` to `application.properties`, but it doesn't change anything. I think that's the default behavior within Spring transactions anyway.

Comment: The default behavior for @Transactional is to rollback only for runtime exceptions. 
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)

Comment: That's only true in regular code. In Spring transactional tests, rollback is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Make your test methods public because, from [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop):

> Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, calls within
>   the target object are, by definition, not intercepted. For JDK
>   proxies, only public interface method calls on the proxy can be
>   intercepted.

If the method is not public, no error is thrown.

I suppose you are using the default (JDK proxies, not CGLIB)

Comment: Actually, JUnit 5 doesn't require public methods for tests, but I made that change and it didn't help. I've done it in JUnit 4, too, with the same result.

Comment: Btw, that's an entirely reasonable suggestion, because as you say Spring only advises public methods. But it still didn't matter, and I could see in the logging output that the transactions were being rolled back anyway.

Comment: @kousen Can you make a proof-of-concept like project on Github?

Comment: @kousen If you don't make the method public you have no transaction active, I don't know what rollback do you see in the logs.

Comment: I'll add it to github later today, but the code is exactly the code I posted above (other than the tests and test classes are all public).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is your problem but I was getting the same behavior because I was using "peek" inside a stream which was creating a thread and its own transaction and when tests were run all together it was leaving rows inside the database. When they were run one by one that did not happen. Be sure that no new threads are being created and not controlled inside your code